# Ring buffer in Ruby

Tags: performance, ruby, circular-list

I was just reading about ring buffer the other day and I was fascinated by how simple yet efficient it is.

I've implemented a ring (circular) buffer in Ruby and I'm just wondering if there's anything I can improve, and also how to properly measure its performance.

Ring buffer:

```
class RingBuffer

  attr_accessor :ring, :size, :start, :end

  def initialize(size)
    @ring = Array.new(size)
    @size = size
    @start, @end = 0, 0
  end

  def full?
    (@end + 1) % @size == @start
  end

  def empty?
    @end == @start
  end

  def write(element)
    return if full?

    @ring[@end] = element
    @end = (@end + 1) % @size
  end

  def read
    return if empty?

    element = @ring[@start]
    @start = (@start + 1) % @size
    element
  end

  def clear
    @ring = Array.new(@size)
    @start, @end = 0, 0
  end

end
```

Speed test:

```
require_relative 'ring_buffer.rb'

buffer_size = 1024*1024
rb = RingBuffer.new(buffer_size)

t0 = Time.now
(buffer_size-1).times {|idx|
  rb.write idx
}
t1 = Time.now
(buffer_size-1).times {|idx|
  rb.read
}
t2 = Time.now

t_all = (t2-t0) * 1000.0
t_avg_w = (t1 - t0) * 1000.0 * 1000.0 / buffer_size
t_avg_r = (t2 - t1) * 1000.0 * 1000.0 / buffer_size

printf("All: %.02fms\n", t_all)
printf("Avg. write: %.02fÎ¼s\n", t_avg_w)
printf("Avg. read: %.02fÎ¼s\n", t_avg_r)
```

Comment: There's a link to github repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things:

- You declare accessors: Use them yourself. Don't access instance variables directly if you can help it; you'll keep you code more flexible if your object uses its own accessor methods. In other words: Drop most of those `@` chars (though you'll have to use `self.end` to distinguish it from the `end` keyword)
- *However*, for the most part, you'll only want public *reader* methods. Otherwise anyone can just mess with the internal `ring` array from the outside (sure, you can always mess with stuff in Ruby objects, but making it part of your object's declared interface makes it too easy).
  In fact, I'd probably pare it allll the way down to just `read`, `write`, `empty?` and `full?` with no public accessors and keep the rest private.
- You could consider adding a method to do the oft-duplicated `(x + 1) % size` trick for you.

---

As for performance: Using a normal array with `push` and `shift` is much faster I'm afraid. And there's no fixed size. So if you want a fast FIFO buffer/queue in plain Ruby, use an array.

This:

```
buffer_size = 1024**2
buffer = RingBuffer.new(buffer_size)

puts "RingBuffer#write"
puts Benchmark.measure {
  buffer_size.times { |i| buffer.write(i) }
}

puts "RingBuffer#read"
puts Benchmark.measure {
  buffer_size.times { buffer.read }
}

puts "----------------------------------"

array = []

puts "Plain Array#push"
puts Benchmark.measure {
  buffer_size.times { |i| array << i }
}

puts "Plain Array#shift"
puts Benchmark.measure {
  buffer_size.times { array.shift }
}
```

gets me:

```
RingBuffer#write
  0.560000   0.000000   0.560000 (  0.563023)
RingBuffer#read
  0.400000   0.000000   0.400000 (  0.400563)
----------------------------------
Plain Array#push
  0.120000   0.000000   0.120000 (  0.139201)
Plain Array#shift
  0.170000   0.000000   0.170000 (  0.164827)
```

So writing/pushing is ~4.7 times faster, and reading/shifting is ~2.4 times faster with a regular ol' Array.

Comment: This is just some excellent input. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I'm not sure though, how Array is faster. I've tried benchmarking this scenario: I fill both up (array and ring buffer) then I read/shift, and then a write/push. Shouldn't in this case ring buffer be faster since it's wrapping around and not shifting?

Comment: @MatjazMuhic `Array` will likely _always_ be faster because it's compiled C code. It exposes a Ruby API, so it feels like it's just Ruby, but its guts are C. Your implementation, when written in Ruby, is basically an extra layer (interpreted, not compiled) on top of that. So nothing you write in Ruby will be as close to metal as built-in, compiled code. You might be able to make a fast circular buffer in C, though, with bindings for Ruby. But that's a very different topic, of course.

Comment: But I'm not doing anything cpu expensive since underneath it's using the array, but without shifting. This implementation for example should be faster than normal array: https://github.com/bbcrd/CBuffer

Comment: @MatjazMuhic Array, being compiled, isn't even on the same playing field as your code, regardless of what you're doing. I'll also add that there's something fishy with that library you linked. I tried running its `rake benchmark` task, and with no modifications, Array looks slower. But they've wrapped Array in a class, and (for whatever reason), it _murders_ performance. I upped the iterations from 10,000 to 100,000, and it took so long I just pulled the plug. But skip the (unneccessary) wrapper, and Array again handily beats all-comers - by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @MatjazMuhic [Here's an updated benchmark.rb file](http://pastie.org/private/b6sfjvegkvmkl8yulhdeg) you can drop into that library you linked to and try for yourself. It includes that library's implementation, your implementation, their array-wrapper, and the plain array push/shift.

Comment: Thank for the update. But I still don't quite get it. Read from fixed array position should be faster than shift right?

Comment: @MatjazMuhic Depends on how the array is implemented. I don't know how Ruby's Array is implemented, but a shift could be just a pointer changing - nothing more. In that case it's practically instantaneous. Just `a = b` and done. Your code, meanwhile, does some arithmetic on `start` or `end` values that may or may not even be numeric since Ruby's dynamically typed, so that's checked, which requires some more work, and blah blah. And it _still_ has to access the underlying array. Again, you're not even playing by the same rules as Ruby here. You're comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no ruby guy but just from a general point of view I try to see data structures from an abstract interface point of view. And your interface looks like a fixed size FIFO queue. The fact that you implemented it as a ring buffer is just an implementation detail really. So I'd be inclined to rename it to `FixedSizeQueue`, `write` to `enqueue` and read to `dequeue` which seems more natural names for the operations as you have implemented them.

Comment: But, fixed size queue doesn't actually wrap around does it? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @MatjazMuhic: Well, what does it matter to the user? As a user you can write `N` items into the structure until it's full. And you can read from it until it's empty. And you will get the items out of it in the same order as they were put in. To me that's a fixed sized queue. What underlying implementation you use is not really relevant for the user (in most cases).

Comment: Well I guess someone would/could choose a ring buffer over a normal queue when the performance is critical? Because there's no overhead of shifting items?

Comment: A fixed size queue generally blocks or raises an error when full instead of simply overwriting old elements like a ring buffer would

Comment: @nijave The particular implementation in this case doesn't overwrite elements - `return if full?`

Comment: @ChrisWue I guess more accurately the question is calling a FixedQueue a ring buffer so I guess there's so ambiguity in regards to what problem the original question was trying to solve. It seems `ring buffer` more commonly refers to a data structure that overwrites data automatically https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer